# Lost text recovery

Tags: applications

I have 3 months of lost text messages from 2019 , they were not deleted by me , how can I recover them ? I have a new phone , but the new phone has text from 5-5-2019 to 5-10-2019 then 8-2-2019 to final text 1-10-2021

Comment: how did you transfer to new phone